# Android Studio, center image and detect where tapped area inside image

Tags: android, image, android-studio, touch, imagemap

I'm trying to create a centered image on top of the title screen of the app. It should be like a pop-up sort of, and when the user taps on the bottom 1/4 image the app should open a URL, and tapping on the top 3/4 should do nothing. This is the view layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBeach"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/adpopup_test_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've attached an `onTouchListener` to the `imgBeach` which checks the position of the touch-event.

```
imgBeach.setOnTouchListener(this);

//..

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    // set value to dataobject and set possibly corrected value in textview
    if (v == imgBeach) {

        // where clicked in image, get image position
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();

        if (y > (imgBeach.getHeight() * 3) / 4) {
            Log.d("My Title Screen", "BOTTOM 1/4!!");
            // open website..
            //Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.adpopupurl));
            //Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
            //startActivity(launchBrowser);
        } else {
            Log.d("My Title Screen", "TOP 3/4!!");
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

However, the problem is that the view for the image is extended to the top and bottom of the containing view, see yellow rectangle in screenshot below. So when `onTouch` gets called, then how can I detect if it's inside or outside the image? Or is it possible to designate touchAreas or something like that to the image?

[image: android touch event image map]

Comment: Add these two attributes to your `ImageView`: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Answer (score 0):

You can put button  on image in bottom and in xml  :android:background="@null"